# logback 1.3.0-alpha5: multiple logger but only the lastone works

Tags: logback

I recently upgraded logback from 1.2.7 to logback-classic:1.3.0-alpha5. However, the multiple  tags I used to setup not working anymore except only the lastone.

To be clear, my logback.xml seems like

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="project"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.apache.commons" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="project"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.wcc" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="errorLog"/>
    <appender-ref ref="project"/>
</logger>
<!-- dubbo ErrorLog -->
<logger name="org.apache.dubbo" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="errorLog"/>
    <appender-ref ref="project"/>
</logger>
```

My catalina.out seems like

```
13:05:56,972 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[project] - Active log file name: /opt/dbs/tomcat/logs/openapi/openapi.project.log

13:05:56,972 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[project] - File property is set to [/opt/dbs/tomcat/logs/openapi/openapi.project.log]

13:05:56,972 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler@81605ec - Attaching appender [project] to Logger[org.apache.dubbo]
```

However, only errors and infos appear in package org.apache.dubbo can be printed to my log files. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Can you provide a complete configuration xml file?

Comment: I also encountered this issue but don't know the actual cause. I just moved the <root> section above the <logger> section and it started logging again.